# Invalid XML path keys still evaluate in Rest Assured

Tags: rest-assured

My example web service is returning following XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<errorResponse>
<errorCode>Wrong ID</errorCode>
<errorId>2</errorId>
</errorResponse>
```

Following tests are passed.

```
response.then().body("errorResponse.errorId", Matchers.is("2"));
response.then().body("errorResponse.errorCode", Matchers.is("Wrong ID"));

response.then().body("errorResponse1.errorCode", Matchers.is("Wrong ID"));
response.then().body("errorResponse2.errorCode", Matchers.is("Wrong ID"));
```

I understand that first two tests are fine, what I am not getting is why the last two are getting passed?

Comment: complete code and details from this blog post: https://www.journaldev.com/21501/rest-assured-tutorial#rest-assured-xml-rest-web-services-example

Comment: It seems like errorResponse2/errorResponse1 are not part of the xml response.. perhaps did you try to change `Matchers.is("Wrong ID")` into `Matchers.is("Bla Bla")` and see how it reacts ? also, is there a chance that the xml you provided doesn't relate to the `response` in the test code ? perhaps you can dump the response to stdout from the code ?

Comment: I reproduced OP's issue on my machine and even with `"giberishzzz.errorCode"`, the test passes. But it fails on `"errorResponse.errorCodeXXX"`.It's like the first node name is just ignored. Weird. Maybe a bug ? OP has already opened an issue 13 days ago but nobody answered (https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/issues/1034)

Comment: Thanks Keats, I forgot to mention that I had raised GitHub issue too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rest-assured uses its *xml-path* library to evaluate your hamcrest matcher and that library contains the XMLAssertion class which does the actual checking.

The source can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/xml-path/src/main/groovy/io/restassured/assertion/XMLAssertion.groovy

At line 60 of this file you can see it removes the part of the search key before the first dot, because it recognizes we're evaluating from a root node.

Hence your key:

```
"errorResponse3.errorCode"
```

becomes

```
".errorCode"
```

So it turns out it doesn't matter what this initial path looks like, it assumes it's the name of the root node and discards it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for providing the detailed answer with reference to the API.